# “Click Save button” vs “Click Save”

Tags: technical

I have a user help document where a user is presented with a form. This form has a Save and Cancel button. I am wondering what would be the best way to explain what happens when a user hits Save button. Which one of these would be correct?

1. Click Save button to save your data.
2. Click Save to save your.

Since Save and Cancel are technically buttons, which you click I tend to think that it is better to specify that it is a button. Some others argue that the word "button" is superfluous here.

Comment: Common usage here treats 'Save' as the name / identifier of the 'Save' button. So, just as we would use "Tell Bertram" (and here "Tell the 'Bertram' person" would be unidiomatic), we can use "Click 'Save' ". The identifier-as-a-name quotes round 'Save' are still normal, as _save_ functions as a common word, unlike _Bertram_.  The preposition 'on' is often dropped. // The alternative "Click the Save button" is also fine; the 'the' is often conversationally (or in manualese) dropped, and identifier quotes aren't needed on 'Save' before _button_.

Comment: Both will work. Include the definite article in the first case: "Click the Save button to ...". "Click Save to ..."

Comment: On a practical level, "click save" is good if your user interface designer decides that instead of a clearly defined button there is some other way of selecting "save" such as clickable text or a region of screen around the word "save". "button" ties you to using a particular UI control. Also, there is a large amount of freedom with short on-screen instructions so they don't need to be particularly grammatical (e.g. you can omit "a" or "the") as long as the user can infer what to do, and there are merits to using the shortest text (takes less space, less cluttered, quicker to read).

Comment: I asked a tech writer as he seems to agree that the word "button" is redundant.
@EdwinAshworth would you post an anwer, I will accept it.

Comment: In most technical documentation, you would omit "button," but the name of the UI element would be in bold text: Click **Save**.

Comment: Sorry; 'answers' need the respectability of supporting references from well-known sources, and while I'm sure I could find lots of examples in line with what I've said, it would take much longer to find say dictionary verification.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Comment: @tchrist I didn't understand your comment. Is it about the way the question itself was asked or something else?

Comment: You asked "which of the below are correct" but there's no such thing as a below. :)

Comment: Note how you said "the form has a Save button". You didn't say "the form has Save button". Because that's not English. Likewise and for the exact same reason, the user can click a Save button, or the Save button. But they can't possibly click Save button. Because that's not English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more relevant to [ux.se]. It's not a questions about grammar or semantics, but about appropriateness of words for user interface design, which one is 'better'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is not grammatically correct. Identified items take a definite article:

> Click **the** Save button to save your data.

The second is grammatically correct.

"Save" is the name of something, and there is no need to say what kind of thing it is unless there could be confusion.  We write

> Read 'War and Peace' to understand Russian culture.

We don't write "Read the book 'War and Peace'..." unless there is a danger that the reader might not understand that War and Peace is a book.

Readers will mostly understand that "Save" is a button so your second is probably the best. It is normal to indicate that "Save" is a name by using quotes, italic or bold.

> Click "Save" to save your data.
>
> Click *Save* to save your data.
>
> Click **Save** to save your data.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think there's any benefit here to being so prescriptive. If the button is identifiable in your documentation by just the words "Save button", then I would argue that it's totally unnecessary.

> Save your data.

Let the user make this pitifully small leap. Indicating that it's the action of "clicking" the "Save button" that will save the user's data is like telling someone that it's colouring with the red crayon that will colour the page red.

Comment: You have offered an original contribution here. I write instructions for IT all the time, and never stop to think I might be dumbing down the procedure instead of trusting the reader just a bit more.